# How to do Knockout validation on complex MVC models in a declarative way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

Technically I've got the answer to this question, but unfortunately not the answer I was looking. I had to accept it because the person worked with me all the way, investing lot of effort. Here I am asking the same q-n to get specifically the answer I am after:

What I am after is a *declarative* way of expressing validations on model fields on the Knockout view model:

Having this MVC view model:

```
public class Email
{
  public string Selected { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

and having this Knockout `viewModel`:

```
var viewModel = {
  UserName: ko.observable("@Model.UserName"),
  Emails: ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(@Model.Emails) || []),

  // How to express these: ???
  // Email.Selected: ko.observable().extend({ required: true })
  // Email.Name: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, email: true })

}
```

what changes do I need to make in Knockout `viewModel` to *declaratively* express that.
Essentially it boils down to expressing the Knockout `viewModel` in a similar manner as the MVC one, but using [knockout validation](http://ericmbarnard.github.com/Knockout-Validation/) (instead of [MVC Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)) on fields of that model.

Before you answer please read till the end, its not much text to read, but I am looking for something specific here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have an Email view model,

```
var Email = 
{
    Selected: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
    Name: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, email: true })
}
```

and then use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to automatically populate it for you:

```
var viewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.UserName: ko.observable("@Model.UserName");
    var mapping = {
    'Emails': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Email(options.data);
        }
     }
     self.Emails= ko.mapping.fromJSON(@Html.Json(@Model.Emails), mapping);
}
```

Note that I think that you need to make your view model a function rather than a straight JS object, as I don't think it will work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will take your answer and try to embed it. Will be back. Definitely looks promising. Thanks.